# Verilog/System Verilog restrictions on generate block and continous assignment

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I took the carry look-ahead code from  [link](https://www.nandland.com/vhdl/modules/carry-lookahead-adder-vhdl.html#:%7E:text=Example%203%3A%204%2DBit%20Carry%20Lookahead%20Adder%20in%20Verilog&text=two%20adder%20inputs.-,This%20is%20because%20two%20N%20bit%20vectors%20added%20together%20can,%7B%2C%20%7D%20Verilog%20concatenation%20operator.) and modified it to be wrong. The part I modified are  `assign w_G[jj]   = (i_add1 & w_P[jj]); assign w_P[jj]   = i_add1[jj] | w_G[jj];`, now simulating the cirucit using icarus causes the simulator to hang. I want to figure what is causing the simulator to behave in such a way. However, commenting the above lines one after the other poses no problem to the simulator.

Fulladder.sv

```
module fulladder(input logic i_bit1,i_bit2, i_carry, output logic o_sum, o_carry);
    assign {o_carry, o_sum} = i_bit1 + i_bit2 + i_carry;
endmodule : fulladder
```

Carry look-ahead module (wrong though)

```
`include "fulladder.sv"
 
module carry_lookahead_adder
  #(parameter WIDTH=3)
  (
   input [WIDTH-1:0] i_add1,
   input [WIDTH-1:0] i_add2,
   output [WIDTH:0]  o_result
   );
     
  logic [WIDTH:0]     w_C;
  logic [WIDTH-1:0]   w_G, w_P, w_SUM;
 
  // Create the Full Adders
  genvar             ii;
  generate
    for (ii=0; ii<WIDTH; ii=ii+1) 
      begin
        fulladder full_adder_inst
            ( 
              .i_bit1(i_add1[ii]),
              .i_bit2(i_add2[ii]),
              .i_carry(w_C[ii]),
              .o_sum(w_SUM[ii]),
              .o_carry()
              );
      end
  endgenerate
 
  // Create the Generate (G) Terms:  Gi=Ai*Bi
  // Create the Propagate Terms: Pi=Ai+Bi
  // Create the Carry Terms:
  genvar             jj;
  generate
    for (jj=0; jj<WIDTH; jj=jj+1) 
      begin
        assign w_G[jj]   = (i_add1 & w_P[jj]);
        assign w_P[jj]   = i_add1[jj] | w_G[jj];
        assign w_C[jj+1] = w_G[jj] | (w_P[jj] & w_C[jj]);
      end
  endgenerate
   
  assign w_C[0] = 1'b0; // no carry input on first adder
 
  assign o_result = {w_C[WIDTH], w_SUM};   // Verilog Concatenation
 
endmodule // carry_lookahead_adder
```

Testbench

````
`include "cla.sv"
 
module carry_lookahead_adder_tb ();
 
  parameter WIDTH = 3;
 
  logic [WIDTH-1:0] r_ADD_1 = 0;
  logic [WIDTH-1:0] r_ADD_2 = 0;
  logic [WIDTH:0]  w_RESULT;
   
  carry_lookahead_adder #(.WIDTH(WIDTH)) carry_lookahead_inst
    (
     .i_add1(r_ADD_1),
     .i_add2(r_ADD_2),
     .o_result(w_RESULT)
     );
 
  initial
    begin
      #10;
      r_ADD_1 = 3'b000;
      r_ADD_2 = 3'b001;
      #10;
      r_ADD_1 = 3'b010;
      r_ADD_2 = 3'b010;
      #10;
      r_ADD_1 = 3'b101;
      r_ADD_2 = 3'b110;
      #10;
      r_ADD_1 = 3'b111;
      r_ADD_2 = 3'b111;
      #10;
    end
 
endmodule // carry_lookahead_adder_tb
```
````

Comment: Simulator hangs are sometimes caused by 0-delay loops, like combinatorial feedback loops. Other tools might show you exactly where the loop is occurring. You can also ttry to add `#1` delays to your continuous assignments.

Comment: Do you intend to create a combinational loop?

Comment: @dave_59 Sure, will do that. Is it good practice to add delays in modules.

Comment: @Light a combinational circuit, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simulator hangs are sometimes caused by 0-delay loops, like combinatorial feedback loops. Other tools might show you exactly where the loop is occurring. You can also try adding `#1` delays to your continuous assignments. Then time can advance and you might be able to see oscillations of your signals in the waveform.

Comment: what about the cyclic dependecies happening here  `assign w_G[jj]   = (i_add1 & w_P[jj]); assign w_P[jj]   = i_add1[jj] | w_G[jj];`, I know the logic is wrong but are these bad in circuit design and any reason why this?

Comment: Have you ever been in a room where someone had a microphone in the wrong spot and you heard a horrible screech? That's a feedback loop. If this happens in hardware it could burn up your device which I say is _bad circuit design_.

Comment: how different is that from some say `assign w_G[jj]   = assign w_G[jj]  & a`

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Please check your syntax.

Comment: my bad `assign w_G[jj]   = w_G[jj]  & a`. Kind of a feedback too or?

Comment: That code also makes no sense. Assuming `w_G[jj]` starts out with an unknown value, how could it have a value other than 0 after `a` first goes to 0. Most synthesis tools generally cannot handle cyclic combinational logic. They want you to model as a latchhttps://www.doulos.com/knowhow/verilog/synthesizing-latches/